# How to pull Facebook news feeds onto website using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook

There seem to be various example using PHP, but need a concrete example of how to do this using .NET.

Facebook seems to be a pain and does not have an easy method like Twitter where you use a widget and it creates the code for you to integrate into your HTML.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use widgets, like the [Twitter widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets), you can access facebook widgets here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Comment: Looked at this, but it requires a potential user to our website to be logged into facebook to see the full news feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provide api for it. Please refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed)

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=your_access_token